# Change values of targeted element in React Native

Tags: react-native, element, target, react-functional-component

Using a functional component, I want to reach the targeted element I pressed and so interact/change the value of it. Right now I'm doing this (using style parem as example), and it works.

But... how can I do it in a more dynamic way if I have much more different elements?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';


const TestScreen = (props) => {

    const [isA, setA] = useState(false);
    const [isB, setB] = useState(false);
    const [isC, setC] = useState(false);

    return (
       <View style={[isA ? styles.on : styles.off]} onPress={() => setA(!isA)}></View>
       <View style={[isB ? styles.on : styles.off]} onPress={() => setA(!isB)}></View>
       <View style={[isC ? styles.on : styles.off]} onPress={() => setA(!isC)}></View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens that you need to choose one of many. For this I propose this [solution](https://medium.com/@raoffonom/react-native-selector-5bff7b1141c6?sk=3a93226c8a8b8279f1a50db32cc06451).